# STM32: How to make a periodic UART Tx with TIM_UP DMA

Tags: timer, stm32, uart, dma, hal

I want to transmit 4 Bytes of data periodically with TIM_UP DMA. i.e when a timer update occurs (or Timer overflows), timer DMA send 4 Bytes with UART. Could someone help me?

Comment: do it in the timer interrupt.

Comment: Can be relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/547695/stm32-how-to-trigger-a-dma-transfer-via-hardware-timer-while-cpu-is-in-sleep/547717#547717